# What's the best way to document an array of arrays of arrays using JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have the following data structure. The element types of the root array are fixed. What is the best way to document such a structure using JSDoc?

```
[
    [
        ['aqua-160', 160, 'PreCleaning'],
        ['aqua-260', 260, 'PreCleaning']
    ],
    [
        ['aqua-360', 360, 'PostCleaning']
    ]
];
```

Comment: `@typedef Array[Array[string|number]] whatever` would be my guess. But tbh, JSDoc has *many* problems documenting modern JS anyway, especially when it comes to destructuring function arguments, or using rest spread, or ... It's just like the problem with bundlers like webpack and many other libraries/tools around the JS ecosystem. JS develops too quickly nowadays, especially with Chromium integrating many stage 3 proposals early. The tooling cannot keep up.

Comment: @connexo Yes, this is correct. All I'm trying to do is replace the use of TypeScript with a simpler solution that just checks the types as the code is written (not compiled) in the JS files. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: As I'm not a fan of any technologies that cannot be run directly in the browser as-is, I can get behind your approach. https://medium.com/@trukrs/type-safe-javascript-with-jsdoc-7a2a63209b76

Comment: @connexo Whoa! I appreciate the link and the informative answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `@typedef` for this:

```js
/** @typedef {[string, number, string]} MyTuple */
```

Which you can apply as follow:

```js
/** @type {Array<Array<MyTuple>>} */
const x = [ [ ['aqua-160', 160, 'PreCleaning']
            , ['aqua-260', 260, 'PreCleaning']]
          , [ ['aqua-360', 360, 'PostCleaning']]];
```

When you mouse over the `x` variable in VS Code here's what you can see:

[image]

With VS Code you can also do some [type checking](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) with a `// @ts-check` "directive" at the top of the file:

```js
// @ts-check

/**
 * @typedef {[string, number, string]} MyTuple
 */

/** @param {Array<Array<MyTuple>>} z */
function y(z) {
  return 42;
}

y('4');
```

VS Code is able to see that the `z` parameter is wrong:

[image]

**See also**

- https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1703